# Exit from application via button in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am very new to titanium when i am trying to exit from the application by clicking the  button it displays the titanium splash screen again!!

I am using the following code

```
var win=Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#ddd',
    exitOnClose:true        
});

var button=Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'back',
    left:10,top:10  
});

button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    win.close();
});

var text=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Home page',
    color:'#000',
    font:{ fontSize:20} 
});

win.add(button);
win.add(text);

win.open();
```

How can I exit from the application through button click?

Comment: What platform are you using? Android can do this, iOS cannot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply close the application by adding following property to the first window of your application.

```
     exitOnClose: true
```

and then type the following code where you close your window

```
     win.close();
     var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
     activity.finish();
```

Reference : [Exit from Titanium Application Android](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/83911/titaniumappexit-for-android).
Hope it solved your problem!!

Comment: It is exiting from the application but splash screen is displaying before going to exit.

Comment: Write the code at the first most window. Just check inside applicationWindow.js.