# Quit Android app in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, quit

I want quit the Android app suppose my app having quit button when i click on that button i need to close the all app data and navigate to Mobile home screen for that i am writing the code to close to current activity 
     var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
    activity.finish();

```
by this i am close the current activity how i will close the app programatically.

Thanks in Advance....
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer at [Exit from application via button in titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605653/exit-from-application-via-button-in-titanium/13618254#13618254). You can also refer [Exit Titanium android application](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/83911/titaniumappexit-for-android). Both answers will help you to resolve your issue